# Как удалить все повторяющиеся слова из файла?

Tags: c#

У меня есть файл, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
id_one
id1212121
id18839801
id18
id1212121
id18
id_one
```

Все слова идут в столбик. Как сделать так, чтоб в файле не было повторяющихся слов?

Comment: Как еще один вариант - использовать хэш-таблицу со словом в качестве ключа. Но это уже не так изящно и кратко.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если порядок не важен, то так:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
        outputPath,
        File.ReadLines(inputPath).Distinct());
```